AsyncClient.init() proxy argument error in Azure AI Foundry WebApp deployment
I'm encountering an issue deploying my web app in Azure AI Foundry.
Error
AsyncClient.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
I havent created any environment variables for the proxies nor do I have any proxy route.
I have tried deploying gpt4o mini and llama and both the models have the same issue.
I have tried adding the http_proxy and https_proxy but that did not work. I tried removing authentication and that did not work either. I tried changing the location too


If you're not using proxies remove http_proxy or https_proxy.


Error AsyncClient.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

The models internally use a library like httpx for HTTP requests. The proxies argument be incorrectly passed due to outdated or mismatched library versions.

Check the model's dependencies in requirements.txt or pyproject.toml.

If the dependency is locked by the environment, modify the deployment script or contact Azure AI Foundry support to adjust pre-installed library versions.


Azure AI Foundry might include a pre-configured script or template that assumes proxy usage and incorrectly adds a proxies argument.
Go to Foundry's Networking or Configuration section in the Azure portal. Disable Proxy Settings at Foundry Level
Add openai==1.55.3 to your requirements.txt to lock the version and avoid unintended issues caused by future updates please check this link and also refer this.
